# Chef Ohai plugin infinite loop, resources leak and shell out risk minimizing

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Usually, Ohai plugin runs periodically to collect some host parameters and some of the plugins usually added to all nodes in the company. This could be sensitive for resources using and how Ohai handle that. So I have two questions here.

The first one is what will happen if I will put infinite loop accidentally? Does Ohai/ruby has some max heap size or any memory limits?

Second question would be about shell out in Ohai. Is it possible to reduce timeout? Do you know more protections just in case?

I use only special ruby timeout for now:

```
require 'timeout'
begin
  status = Timeout::timeout(600) {
    # all code here
  }
rescue Timeout::Error
  puts 'timeout'
end
```

Comment: How is this related to [tag:json]?

Comment: I've added this just because node attributes are in json

Comment: They are not ;-) Or.. depends on how at what place you see it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I have found solution to limit Ohai resources for Redhat Linux in terms of CPU, disk space usage, disk space I/O, long run timeout and heap size memory limit. So you will not affect other host's components. In ideal world, you write optimised and right code, but memory leak is global problem and could happen so I think protections are needed especially when you have loaded Ohai plugin to hunders or tousands production servers.

**CPU -**
If I'm right Ohai plugin gets lowest cpu priority (-19?). Please confirm this if you know. So Ohai plugin cannot affect your production app in terms of CPU.

**Disk space -**
Ohai plugin should write to node attributes

**Protection for unexpected long run -**

```
    require 'timeout'
    begin
      status = Timeout::timeout(600) {
        # Ohai plugin code is here
      }
    rescue Timeout::Error
      puts 'timeout'
    end
```

**Protection for unexpected long run of shell_out:**

```
so = shell_out("/bin/your-command", :timeout => 30)
```

**Memory (RAM) heap size limit -**

```
require "thread"
# This thread is memory watcher. It works separately and does exit if heap size reached.
# rss is checked including childs but excluding shared memory.
# This could be ok for Ohai plugin. I'm assuming memory is not shared.
# Exit - if heap size limit reached (10 000 KB) or any unexpected scenario happened.
Thread.start {
  loop do
    sleep 1
    current_memory_rss = `ps ax -o pid,rss | grep -E "^[[:space:]]*#{$$}"`.strip.split.map(&:to_i)[1].to_i

    if current_memory_rss != nil && current_memory_rss > 0 && $$ != nil && $$.to_i > 0
      exit if current_memory_rss > 10_000
    else
      exit
    end
  end
}

# Your Ohai code begins here
# For testing, any code can be included to make memory growing constantly as infinite loop:
loop do
  puts `ps ax -o pid,rss | grep -E "^[[:space:]]*#{$$}"`.strip.split.map(&:to_i)[1].to_s + ' KB'
end
```

Please let me know if you have better solutions, but it seems it works.

**Disk I/O read heavy usage -**
timeout should help here, but recommended to avoid commands like `find` and similar others

Answer (score 1):

The chef-client run won't start/succeed, if *ohai* hangs.. you should notice this in some kind of monitoring.

Regarding the *timeout* part: Searching the source code reveals [this](https://github.com/chef/ohai/blob/13485c17da688654890047d1952d9f71e735d162/lib/ohai/mixin/command.rb#L33-L36):

```rb
def shell_out(cmd, **options)
  # unless specified by the caller timeout after 30 seconds
  options[:timeout] ||= 30
  so = Mixlib::ShellOut.new(cmd, options)
```

So you should be able to set the timeout as you like (2 seconds in this case):

```rb
so = shell_out("/bin/your-command", :timeout => 2)
```

Regarding the third sub-question

> Do you know more protections just in case?

you are getting pretty broad. Try to solve the problems that occur, stop over-engineering.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen some Ohai issues and Ohai rollback is not that simple when chef client is affected. The plugin file stored locally. So I wanted to discuss here if you know how the plugin can be limited to not affect other host components. I know that this is a bit of over-engineering, but having some limits like in Java heap size max or something else would be great.

Comment: I see, from that perspective it really makes sense :)
Not sure if there's such thing as "heap" in Ruby..

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness, Chef does not guard against broken or malicious Ohai plugins. If you put `sleep 1 while true` in your Ohai plugin it will happily sit there forever.